# Update data in Kartik Detailview is not working

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I've detail showed using Kartik Detail View. This widget has Edit inline function by clicking pencil icon button in top right side like this.
[image]

But then the table doesn't be editable :
[image]

And nothing happen, my data still the same, my update not success. **It's possible to solve my problem**? Thanks.

I have read the official guide and it looks identical:
https://demos.krajee.com/detail-view

**This is my view code:**

```
<?php echo DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $modelAnagrafiche,
        'responsive' => true,
        'mode' => 'edit',
        'enableEditMode' => true,
        'buttons1' => '{update}',
        'panel' => [
            'type' => 'primary',
            'heading' => 'Contratto' . ' : ' . $modelAnagrafiche >cognome_ragione_sociale . ' ' . $modelAnagrafiche->nome
        ],
        'attributes' => [
            [
                'group'=>true,
                'label'=>'Sezione Anagrafica',
                'rowOptions'=>['class'=>'table-primary']
            ],
            [
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'cognome_ragione_sociale',
                        'displayOnly' => true,
                        'valueColOptions' => ['style' => 'width:30%']
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'nome',
                        'format' => 'raw',
                        'valueColOptions' => ['style' => 'width:30%'],
                        'displayOnly' => true,
                        'type' => DetailView::INPUT_TEXT,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'codice_fiscale',
                        'displayOnly' => true,
                        'valueColOptions' => ['style' => 'width:30%']
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'partita_iva',
                        'format' => 'raw',
                        'valueColOptions' => ['style' => 'width:30%'],
                        'displayOnly' => true
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'tipo_documento',
                        'displayOnly' => true,
                        'valueColOptions' => ['style' => 'width:30%'],
                        'format' => 'raw',
                        'value' => $modelAnagrafiche->tipoDocumento,
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'numero_documento',
                        'format' => 'raw',
                        'valueColOptions' => ['style' => 'width:30%'],
                        'displayOnly' => true
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'data_nascita',
                        'displayOnly' => true,
                        'format' => 'date',
                        'type' => DetailView::INPUT_DATE,
                        'widgetOptions' => [
                            'pluginOptions' => ['format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd']
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'id_provincia_nascita',
                        'displayOnly' => true,
                        'valueColOptions' => ['style' => 'width:30%'],
                        'format' => 'raw',
                        'value' => $modelAnagrafiche->provinciaNascitaNome,
                        'label' => 'Provincia Nascita'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'id_comune_nascita',
                        'displayOnly' => true,
                        'format' => 'raw',
                        'value' => $modelAnagrafiche->comuneNascitaNome,
                        'label' => 'Comune Nascita'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

**This is the action in my controller**:

```
public function actionUpdateAnagrafica()
{
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

    if (empty($post['Anagrafiche']['id'])) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Non esiste nessuna anagrafica.');
    }

    $modelAnagrafiche = Anagrafiche::findOne($post['Anagrafiche']['id']);

    if ($modelAnagrafiche->load($post) && $modelAnagrafiche->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $modelAnagrafiche->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update-anagrafica', [
            'modelAnagrafiche' => $modelAnagrafiche,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove all the `displayOnly` attributes.

According to the official guide:

> displayOnly: boolean|Closure, if the input is to be set to as display
>   only in edit mode. If set to true, no editable form input will be
>   displayed, instead this will display the formatted attribute value.